# How can i 'break' when first occurence in a HashMap value is met?

Tags: java, hashmap, return

Below you can see my code snippet where i try to identify what is the country of origin of a given telephone number. The problem is that it always return the last key of the compared string values.

I have sorted my HashMap by value in desc order and then compared given String with each value in HashMap using startWith method.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CountryFinder {

    static Map<String, String> countriesNamesAndCodes;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        countriesNamesAndCodes = new HashMap<>();
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("Greece", "30");
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("Italy", "39");
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("Germany", "49");
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("USA", "1");
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("UK", "44");
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("Bahamas", "1-242");
        countriesNamesAndCodes.put("ExampleCountry", "301");

        for (Entry<String, String> entry : countriesNamesAndCodes.entrySet()) {
            if (entry.getValue().contains("-")) {
                String tempValue = entry.getValue().replaceAll("-", "");
                entry.setValue(tempValue);
            }
        }

        countriesNamesAndCodes.entrySet().stream().sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        String input = String.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Type a telephone number"));
        System.out.println(input);
        System.out.println("Origin Country: " + getCountry(input));

    }

    private static String getCountry(String telephoneNumber) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : countriesNamesAndCodes.entrySet()){
            if (telephoneNumber.startsWith(entry.getValue())) {
                return (entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

When the input is 1242888999 or 1-242888999 i expect the output of "Bahamas" , but the actual output is "USA". Same goes for input 301555666, i expect "ExampleCountry" instead of "Greece".

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that this line keeps the `HashMap` sorted: it only sorts the stream for printing.

```
countriesNamesAndCodes.entrySet().stream()
   .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
   .forEach(System.out::println);
```

This means that when you loop over the map's entry set later, you are subject to the order in which it travels the hash map, and Java makes no guarantees about that order ([the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) even says that the order may change over time).

You might want to look into a [SortedMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

`HashMap` is not sorted. You can not rely on its order, as it is mostly `hashCode()` based.

However your problem is not related to order, it is because you are not selecting the longest prefix (the value with the highest length): if you look for 1-242, then USA (1) and Bahamas (1-242) works. Same goes for ExampleCountry (301) and Greece (30).

Your algorithm should be something like that: for each entry for which the phone number starts with the entry' value, we remember the "best match" entry and update it whenever it was never found (initial case) or its value is bigger than previously matched.

```
private static String getCountry(String telephoneNumber) {
    var bestMatch = null; // Map.Entry<String,String>
    for (Entry<String, String> entry : countriesNamesAndCodes.entrySet()){
      if (telephoneNumber.startsWith(entry.getValue()) {
        if (bestMatch == null || entry.getValue().length() > bestMatch.getValue().length()) {
          bestMatch = entry;
        }
      }
    }
    return null != bestMatch ? bestMatch.getKey():null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code executed exactly what it was written to do, and your issue is here

```
   private static String getCountry(String telephoneNumber) {
        for (Entry<String, String> entry : countriesNamesAndCodes.entrySet()){
            if (telephoneNumber.startsWith(entry.getValue())) {
                return (entry.getKey());
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You are extracting first search matching entry value which in your case (1-242888999) start with 1, so it will bring the entry = 1 which is USA.

**The reason** is that you are ordering using streams in place, and when you entered the getCountry you became out of order again, so you need to save first your ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Combining elements from a few of the other answers, you might want to keep a `SortedMap` from the country codes to the countries' names, sorted in descending length order (with ties broken by alphabetic order).

That way, the longest match is always checked first, so you don't run into the same prefix problem.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import static java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
import static java.util.Comparator.naturalOrder;

class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SortedMap<String, String> codeCountries = new TreeMap<>(
        comparingInt(String::length)
          .reversed()
          .thenComparing(naturalOrder()));

    codeCountries.putAll(Map.of(
        "1", "United States",
        "1241", "Bahamas",
    ));

    for (String name : codeCountries.values) {
        System.out.println(name);
        // Prints "United States", then "Bahamas"
    }
  }
}
```

The only other change you would need would be that you would have to remove the dashes from the country codes *before* putting them in the map. If you don't, both keys will remain in the map.

As a similar, potentially faster (but not so much faster that it would really matter) alternative, you could keep a non-sorted map with the country codes as its keys, and whenever you get an input, you could try getting all of its prefixes from the map:

```
Map<String, String> countryCodes = Map.of("1242", "Bahamas", "1", "United States");

String input = /* get some input */;

for (int i = input.length; i > 0; --i) {
    String country = countryCodes.get(input.substring(0, i));
    if (country != null) {
        return country;
    }
}
// If you get here, no country code was found in the map.

// Alternatively, with streams:
IntStream.range(0, input.length())
  .mapToObj(i -> input.substring(0, input.length() - i))
  .filter(countryCodes::containsKey)
  .findFirst();
```

However, a more reliable idea than worrying about parsing country codes or detecting overlap between them (especially if your users sometimes forget to include their country code) would be to ask for the country code first, then the rest of the number. Then you could just look up the country code directly, without worrying about overlaps.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a new method and tried to save the temporary Stream ordering in another Map. Now it works!

```
    private static Map<String, String> sortMapByValuesDesc(Map<String, String> unsortedMap) {

    return sortedMap = unsortedMap
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()))
            .collect(
                    toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e2, LinkedHashMap::new));

}
```